# How to remove 'Create New Order' button from sales order grid

Tags: grid, uicomponent, order-grid

[image]

How can I remove 'Create New Order' button from sales order grid?

I don't want to hide it, i know about following code

```
<item name="style" xsi:type="string">display:none</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a module in `app/code/Vendor/Module`

1. Create an XML file `view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="add" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Buttons\EmptyButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

2. Create the Ui Component class `Ui/Component/Listing/Buttons/EmptyButton.php`

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Buttons;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;

class EmptyButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData(): array
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Clear the cache, and the "Create New Order" button should be removed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the below instead

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
  </item>
</argument>
```